# Can Boost.Pfr be used to iterate the fields of a type as member pointers?

Tags: c++, boost, c++17

I know that Boost.Pfr can be used to iterate the fields of a type, and visit them as a `T&`, but since `T&` can't be cast to `T A::*`, I'm wondering if there's something in the library I missed that can allow visiting fields as member pointers.

```cpp
#include <boost/pfr.hpp>

struct A {
    int number;
    string text;
};

int main() {
    boost::pfr::for_each_field(A{1,"foo"},
        [](auto A::* field) { // wish this or something similar were possible
            
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: I'm fairly confident that's just not possible without some macro magic. At least not with PFR. You would want some actual reflection to get type information.

Comment: Related  https://github.com/boostorg/pfr/issues/60

Comment: @sehe interesting link, but works in wrong direction: from pointer to member to index of field. Here it is expected to get pointer to member (possibly form index).

Comment: @MarekR it was just a related question - highlighting that ptm's are not a first-class citizen in the PFR interface. As you can see from my answer (that confirms super's comment) I understood the direction of the question, which is why this was only a comment.

Answer (score 0):

PFR doesn't have this (yet?) but if you have recent enough Boost, Describe could be what you're after.

Note it isn't as auto-magic as with PFR, but it does give you the member-pointer information to work with at compile time.

In their "Universal Print Example" you can see that the member descriptor object contains a member `pointer` which is of pointer-to-member type:

```
using Md = describe_members<T, mod_any_access>; // for exposition

boost::mp11::mp_for_each<Md>([&](auto D){

    if( !first ) { os << ", "; } first = false;

    os << "." << D.name << " = " << t.*D.pointer;

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't get a pointer to a member function. But you can iterate over fields without having an object present. The resulting indices and types can be used in a similar way to member pointers, i.e. with objects supplied later. You can get the tuple size at compile time using `boost::pfr::tuple_size<T>::value>{}`, and then compile-time iterate over fields of a class using a comma fold (having made an index sequence of tuple size).

Here is a sketch of a possible approach, which is a bit more general than I've needed so far, but hopefully illustrates the point.

```
template <typename T, size_t I>
struct PfrMemFunPtr
{
    using type = T;
    using value_type = boost::pfr::tuple_element_t<I, T>;
    static constexpr size_t idx = I;
};

template <typename T, typename F, size_t... I>
void apply_impl(F&& f, std::index_sequence<I...>)
{
    (f(PfrMemFunPtr<T, I>{}), ...);
}
template <typename T, typename F>
void apply(F&& f)
{
    apply_impl<T>(std::forward<F>(f),
                  std::make_index_sequence<boost::pfr::tuple_size<T>::value>{});
}

struct P
{
    int i1 = 1;
    std::string h = "hello";
    int i2 = 2;
    std::string_view w = "world";
};

// Create vector of type-erased functions, which output each field given ostream + object
std::vector<std::function<void(std::ostream&, const P&)>> vec;
apply<P>([&](auto pfr_mem_fun_ptr) {
    vec.push_back([&](std::ostream& os, const P& p) {
            os << boost::pfr::get<pfr_mem_fun_ptr.idx>(p) << '\n'; }); });

P p;
for(auto&& f : vec)
    f(std::cout, p);
```

Output

```
1
hello
2
world
```